# curtains.js — Unable to initialize the shader program

Tags: shader, webgl, curtains.js

I'm attempting to add a fragment shader to plane created via curtains. I've used this fragment shader with other libraries before — namely, canvas-sketch — however I can't seem to get the shader to run as the console prompts me with the error: `Program: Unable to initialize the shader program.`

```css
#canvas {
    /* make the canvas wrapper fits the document */
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
}
.plane {
    /* define the size of your plane */
    width: 80%;
    height: 80vh;
    margin: 10vh auto;
}
```

```html
<div id="canvas"></div>
<div class="plane"></div>
<script type="module">
import { Curtains, Plane } from "https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/curtainsjs@7.1.0/src/index.mjs";

window.addEventListener("load", () => {
  // set up our WebGL context and append the canvas to our wrapper
  const curtains = new Curtains({
    container: "canvas",
  });

  // get our plane element
  const planeElement = document.getElementsByClassName("plane")[0];

  // set our initial parameters (basic uniforms)

  const fragmentShader = `
    precision mediump float;
    uniform float uTime;
    varying vec2 vUv;

    void main() {
        vec3 color = 0.5 + 0.5 * cos(uTime + vUv.xyx + vec3(0.0, 2.0, 4.0));
        gl_FragColor = vec4(color, 1.0);
    }
  `;
  const params = {
    fragmentShader,
    widthSegments: 20,
    heightSegments: 20,
    uniforms: {
      time: {
        name: "uTime", // uniform name that will be passed to our shaders
        type: "1f", // this means our uniform is a float
        value: 0,
      },
    },
  };

  // create our plane using our curtains object, the bound HTML element and the parameters
  const plane = new Plane(curtains, planeElement, params);

  plane.onRender(() => {
    // use the onRender method of our plane fired at each requestAnimationFrame call
    plane.uniforms.time.value++; // update our time uniform value
  });
});
</script>
```

I did see notes in other questions about how to enable more verbose error logging for GL but I'm not sure how to set these properties using this library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

curtains doesn't have a varying called `vUv`. It has one called `vTextureCoord`

```css
#canvas {
    /* make the canvas wrapper fits the document */
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
}
.plane {
    /* define the size of your plane */
    width: 80%;
    height: 80vh;
    margin: 10vh auto;
}
```

```html
<div id="canvas"></div>
<div class="plane"></div>
<script type="module">
import { Curtains, Plane } from "https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/curtainsjs@7.1.0/src/index.mjs";

window.addEventListener("load", () => {
  // set up our WebGL context and append the canvas to our wrapper
  const curtains = new Curtains({
    container: "canvas",
  });

  // get our plane element
  const planeElement = document.getElementsByClassName("plane")[0];

  // set our initial parameters (basic uniforms)

  const fragmentShader = `
    precision mediump float;
    uniform float uTime;
    varying vec2 vTextureCoord;

    void main() {
        vec3 color = 0.5 + 0.5 * cos(uTime + vTextureCoord.xyx + vec3(0.0, 2.0, 4.0));
        gl_FragColor = vec4(color, 1.0);
    }
  `;
  const params = {
    fragmentShader,
    widthSegments: 20,
    heightSegments: 20,
    uniforms: {
      time: {
        name: "uTime", // uniform name that will be passed to our shaders
        type: "1f", // this means our uniform is a float
        value: 0,
      },
    },
  };

  // create our plane using our curtains object, the bound HTML element and the parameters
  const plane = new Plane(curtains, planeElement, params);

  plane.onRender(() => {
    // use the onRender method of our plane fired at each requestAnimationFrame call
    plane.uniforms.time.value++; // update our time uniform value
  });
});
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks — very new to shaders and I think I overlooked this in the curtainsjs docs.